# Why does the Virtual Memory Peak size increase with every new thread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, memory, process, pthreads

Recently I've been taking a look at the behavior of my code when tuning my thread pool. I noticed that the virtual memory peak usage grows with every new thread I add to the thread pool, in a way not related to the thread text size or anything else.

I created a simple test program which printed out the VmPeak value ( by parsing the contents of /proc/self/status ) for the process after every new thread is created, and noticed how it would follow a certain pattern ( VmPeak = OriginalVmPeak * numberOfThreads ), until it saturates once a certain level is reached.

I know a thing or two about operating systems and virtual memory, and I know that the virtual memory refers to anything addressable from the point of view of the process ( including libraries and so on ), but why is there a correlation with the thread number, if they share the same addressing space? And why does it saturate after a certain number of threads is reached?

Comment: Probably the stack space allocated for each new thread.